# Electron desktopCapturer to Web API frequency all 0s

Tags: node.js, electron

**==== SOLVED ====**

To be 100% honest I'm not sure what I did, but I have a fully working audio bar visualizer based on desktop audio. I went back to the original codepen (link below) I started working off of and edited everything as needed to accept a media stream, and it works.

**Full Code**

```
const {desktopCapturer} = require('electron')

desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, (error, sources) => {
  if (error) throw error
  for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
     if (sources[i].name === 'Entire screen') {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: { mandatory : { chromeMediaSource: 'desktop' }},
          video: { mandatory : { chromeMediaSource: 'desktop' }}
        })
        .then((stream) => handleStream(stream))
        return
     }
  }
})

function handleStream (stream)
{
  const context = new AudioContext()
  let src = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
  let analyser = context.createAnalyser()

  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

  src.connect(analyser)
  analyser.fftSize = 256

  let bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount
  let dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength)
  let WIDTH = canvas.width
  let HEIGHT = canvas.height
  let barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5
  let barHeight
  let x = 0

   function renderFrame()
   {
      requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame)
      x = 0

      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray)
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

      for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++)
      {
         barHeight = dataArray[i]

         let r = barHeight + (25 * (i / bufferLength))
         var g = 250 * (i/bufferLength)
         var b = 50

         ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
         ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight)

         x += barWidth + 1
      }
   }
   renderFrame()
}
```

**Codepen I used as a starting point**
https://codepen.io/nfj525/pen/rVBaab

**Original Post**

I'm working on setting up a desktop visualizer that will graph the users desktop audio.

desktopCapture appears to be grabbing the media as sending it to a video tag displays the stream, along with an echo of the media. Since I only need the audio, I'm setting the mediaStraem to an AudioContext MediaStreamSource, which also appears to be working as I get an audio echo if I connect the analyser to the ctx destination. The issue I'm running into is when I try to get the frequency data its returning an array of only 0s. Below is my current code

```
const {desktopCapturer} = require('electron')

desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, (error, sources) => {
  if (error) throw error
  for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
     if (sources[i].name === 'Entire screen') {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: {
              mandatory : {
                  chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
              }
          },
          video: {
             mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
             }
          }
        })
        .then((stream) => handleStream(stream))
        return
     }
  }
})

function handleStream (stream) {

   let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
   let source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
   let analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser()

   //uncommenting results in echo, but still all 0s
   //analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination)

   analyser.fftSize = 256
   let bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount
   let dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength)

   console.log(dataArray)

}
```

**===== EDIT =====**

I've been able to get this working; kind of but am still running into a slight issue.

1) I had connect the source and the analyzer with

```
source.connect(analyser)
```

2) Had to fill the dataArray with time domain with

```
getByteTimeDomainData
```

3) Outstanding issue is when there is no media playing the dataArray is filled with values of 126, 127, & 128 making the bars "dance" at almost full height.

4) The FPS also seems extremely fast, but have some plans to fix that

Current somewhat working code :

```
const {desktopCapturer} = require('electron')

desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, (error, sources) => {
  if (error) throw error
  for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
     if (sources[i].name === 'Entire screen') {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: {
              mandatory : {
                  chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
              }
          },
          video: {
             mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
             }
          }
        })
        .then((stream) => handleStream(stream))
        return
     }
  }
})

function handleStream (stream) {

   const audioCtx = new AudioContext()
   let source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
   let analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser()
   source.connect(analyser) //Had To Connect Source To Analyser
   analyser.fftSize = 128

   let bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount
   let dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength)

   let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
   canvas.width = window.innerWidth
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight
   let canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d")

   let WIDTH = canvas.width;
   let HEIGHT = canvas.height;
   let barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength);
   let barHeight;
   let x = 0;

   function draw() {

      var drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw)
      analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray) //added to the draw to fill the dataArray

      canvasCtx.fillStyle = "#000";
      canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

      var x = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i];

        let r = 50
        let g = 250
        let b = 50

        canvasCtx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
        canvasCtx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

        x += barWidth + 1;
      }
   }
draw()
}
```

Comment: This is my exact scenario I have been hunting for for DAYS. exact same issue, all zeros in the array, and using "getByteTimeDomainData makes all my bars max size. Everything works fine with an mp3 file but not with desktop audio. My app is using react so I had to do some wonky stuff with refs to get it working but I cant really tell what your fix was, if there was one?